# Querying Oracle db on Windows Server 2008 from Python

Tags: python, oracle, windows-server-2008

How can I communicate with Oracle database from Python code assuming that a database is run on *Windows Server 2008*? I can communicate it on other OS like Windows XP / Windows Server 2003 / ... using oracle provider OLE DB (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/utilsoft-088126.html) but none of them seem to support Windows Server 2008. May I ask for some hints?

Answer (score 1):

You can user cx_Oracle module to connect oracle from python.

How to user python with oracle?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html

Where is documentation for cx_Oracle?

http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/index.html

This may help to solve your problem.